# Find all LI elements who have a data attribute equal to true

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a set of li elements that have a data attribute of `data-is-archived = true/false` and I need to walk through all li's looking for any `data-is-archived` that is equal to true. Currently when I do:

`$('#comment-section').find('li').data('is-archived')`

I get `false`, which is partially true. There are two LI elements on the page on has this attribute to false, the other is set to true. It seems to stop on the one that is false and not go any further. There could be 500 li elements and 355 of them could be true.

Whats the proper way to get all li elements that have a `data-is-archived=true` back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the relevant attribute-equals selector (and don't use `find()`, it's unnecessary):

```
$('#comment-section li[data-is-archived="true"]')
```

To find out how many have the attribute set to "true":

```
$('#comment-section li[data-is-archived="true"]').length;
```

To find the indices, and return them in an array:

```
$('#comment-section li[data-is-archived="true"]').map(function(i) {
    return i;
}).get();
```

Comment: whats the .get for on the .map?

Comment: "[Without a parameter, `.get()` returns an array of all of the elements...](http://api.jquery.com/get/)"